# OpenCV cannot open video file when run with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I want to open a video file in my OpenCV C++ application with

`cap.open("../../data/Example.MP4");`

but somehow when I run the application in Visual Studio 2015 (I've tried both Debug & Release mode), it cannot find the file.

Surprisingly if I run the application by just double clicking the .exe in Windows Explorer, everything works fine and the video file opens as desired.

Does somebody know why Visual Studio cannot find the file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the Project's Working directory, on Visual Studio. From inside it, it isn't finding the file...

Go to Project Properties, Debugging. There you will see, by default, that the Working directory is your project directory. Change it to **$(OutDir)** and your path should be fixed.